# Как сделать перенос данных на новую базу c другой структурой?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

В общем, делаем проект на Laravel, т.е обновляем старый кастомный проект.
Но заказчик хочет также и перенести данные.

Сложности:

- штук 5 бд (одна для пользователей, и тд)
- старый проект находится на хостинге, где есть только phpmyadmin. А в базе есть таблицы по 1.5GB. Придется по одной таблице грузить.
- пароли хранятся в md5. На новом сайте используется argon

Как лучше сделать перенос данных?

Я думаю, сначала скачать вручную все таблицы, развернуть копию базы со всей структурой на том же серваке. Написать команду Laravel для импорта данных из старой структуры на новую. Только вот с паролями не знаю как быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, сделать первую проверку на вход по md5, и просить пользователя сразу сменить пароль, после валидной авторизации.

Comment: В итоге сделал так, чтобы юзеров был тип "default", "imported_new", "imported_set_password". У пользователя "imported_new" при входе появляется сообщение сменить пароль. После смены пароля его тип равен "imported_set_password".

Сам импорт сделал, прописав в конфиге старое подключение и написав команду, которая копирует данные на новую базу.